# Passing props inorder to use the string value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have the following functional component and de-structuring the parameter props:

```
const MyTimes = ({ myWindowGroup, name, fieldArrayName }) => (

    <FieldArray 
    name={name}
    render={(arrayHelpers) => (
      <React.Fragment>
            {myWindowGroup.fieldArrayName.map((myTime, index) => (
```

and I am calling the component with the following props:

```
    <MyTimes
       myWindowGroup={myWindowGroup}
       fieldArrayName={"myTimes"}
       name={`myWindowGroups.${index}.myTimes`}
    />
```

My question is as I am new to React and that is, how can I pass/use the `fieldArrayName={"myTimes"}` string value of **myTimes** into the `MyTime` component above so that I can replace the value of `fieldArrayName.map` to be `myTimes.map` ?

I've tried it the way it is and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic keys. See [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

```
myWindowGroup[fieldArrayName].map(....
```

```js
const myWindowGroup = {
  myTimes: ['This is the value array you want'],
  foo: [],
};

console.log(myWindowGroup['myTimes']);
console.log(myWindowGroup['foo']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
{myWindowGroup[fieldArrayName].map((myTime, index) => (
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question correctly, you can achieve desired output by following

```
const MyTimes = ({ myWindowGroup, name, fieldArrayName }) => (

    <FieldArray 
    name={name}
    render={(arrayHelpers) => (
      <React.Fragment>
            {myWindowGroup[fieldArrayName].map((myTime, index) => (
             // your logic here
        ))}
```